# Keysight/IXIA application sending incomplete packets

Tags: packet

Currently receiving incomplete packets via Keysight/IXIA. Checked online but unable to find any help and any support would be amazing.

Comment: Samples, or images of what's happening, what you have done would help

Comment: Hi Bharat, this is thru a work project and unfortunately I am unable to add any images or screenshots etc due to confidentiality. Would you have any possible idea what may cause this?.